# pandas series to_dict with repeated indices; make dict with list values

Tags: python, pandas

If you have a neat pandas Series object with unique indices, then using pd.Series.to_dict() works as you might expect it: it becomes a Python dict with each index pointing to its respective value.

This gets complicated if you have non-unique indices. My expected behavior is that values with the same index will get grouped together into a list, and the dict will have the index as a key and the list as a value. What I observe instead is a dict with the index as a key and only a single value from the Series as the value in the dict.

Is there a way to achieve my expected behavior, built into pandas, or close to it? Presently, I manually curate values that match each index into the dict in a for loop, looping over the unique index values. Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:
Here's an example:

```
my_series = pd.Series(['val_1', 'val_2', 'val_3', 'val_4', 'val_5'])
my_series.index = ['1', '1', '2', '2', '2']
my_series
```

Yields

```
1    val_1
1    val_2
2    val_3
2    val_4
2    val_5
dtype: object
```

Now, to_dict() with the 1:1 matching behavior:

```
my_series.to_dict()
{'1': 'val_2', '2': 'val_5'}
```

What I would like to see instead is:

```
{'1': ['val_1', 'val_2'], '2': ['val_3', 'val_4', 'val_5']}
```

I can achieve this doing

```
{idx:list(my_series[idx]) for idx in set(my_series.index)}
{'2': ['val_3', 'val_4', 'val_5'], '1': ['val_1', 'val_2']}
```

What I would like to know is if there is a more native way to do this in pandas, or if this is the best way to handle the problem.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data? Then I'm happy to provide a solution

Comment: I've edited to include an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
my_series.groupby(level=0).agg(list).to_dict()

Out[358]: {'1': ['val_1', 'val_2'], '2': ['val_3', 'val_4', 'val_5']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
my_series.reset_index().groupby('index')[0].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Yields:

```
{'1': ['val_1', 'val_2'], '2': ['val_3', 'val_4', 'val_5']}
```

Comment: I don't know what version of pandas this works for, but in 0.24.1 you can't call `.groupby('index')` without explicitly making a column called index

Comment: `reset_index()` should create a column called `index` by default, in pandas 0.24.2 anyway

Answer (score 1):

Recreating your situation...

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([["a",10], ["b", 11], ["c", 12], ["a", 13]], 
                      columns=["letters", "numbers"])
>>> df.set_index("letters", inplace=True)
>>> print(df.to_dict())
{'numbers': {'a': 13, 'b': 11, 'c': 12}}
```

Ok now we are in your situation.
Lets give it a new index temporarily and group by the duplicated index.

```
>>> df.reset_index(inplace=True)
>>> groups = df.groupby(["letters"])
>>> new_df = groups.numbers.apply(list)
>>> print(new_df.to_dict())
{'a': [10, 13], 'b': [11], 'c': [12]}
```

which is what you asked for.